# Looking if List<T> has <T> (no matter of attribute orders in <T>) in C#

Tags: c#, list

I have `List<Moves> listOfMoves`

```
 ListOfMoves.Add(new Moves()
                        {
                           int position1= number1,
                            int position2= number2,
                        });
```

Now I want to check if `ListOfMoves` contains for example `Move(2,3)`, but also to check if it contains  `Move(3,2)`.
I tried `if(ListOfMoves.Contains(new Move(2,3)))` but this does not work properly.

Comment: Do you want to make this `ListOfMoves.Contains(new Move(2, 3))` work only for type `Moves` or for any type `T`? Why don't you use LINQ: `ListOfMoves.Any(m => (m.position1 == n1 && m.position2. == n2) || (m.position1 == n2 && m.position2. == n1))`?

Comment: You need to override [`Object.Equals()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1) and/or implement [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netcore-3.1) interface on the `Move` class.

Comment: `ListMoves.Any(move => move.position1 == number1 && move.position2 == number2)` will return `true` if condition is `true` at least for one item. Use Linq.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev I will have 8 moves in one if condition to check, so it will basicily make 16 conditions?

Comment: @aepot I need true if both positions are true. `If (list.contains(move 3,2) || list.contains(move2,3)) { true statement}`

Comment: @orhtej2 How to do that?

Comment: You may use for example construction `List.Any(...) && List.Any(..)`. And learn more about **Linq**, there are many useful extensions.

Comment: As @orhtej2 pointed out, you should override [`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1). Go to this link and see an example how `Object.Equals` is implemented in `Point` class. Your implementation should be the same but also it must take into account that order of the properties does not matter.

Comment: You must override **BOTH** `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `List<T>.Contains(T item)` internally uses method [`Object.Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=netcore-3.1) to check if objects are equal. Therefore if you want to use method `List<T>.Contains(T item)` with your type `T` to check if the specified `item` is contained in the `List<T>` then you need to override method `Object.Equals` in your type `T`.

When you override `Object.Equals` you should also override `Object.GetHashCode`. Here is a good explanation ["Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden).

Here is how you should override `Object.Equals` in the `Move` class to fit your requirement:

```
class Move
{
    public Move(int p1, int p2)
    {
        position1 = p1;
        position2 = p2;
    }

    public int position1 { get; }
    public int position2 { get; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            return true;

        Move other = obj as Move;

        if (other == null)
            return false;

        // Here we specify how to compare two Moves. Here we implement your
        // requirement that two moves are considered equal regardless of the
        // order of the properties.
        return (position1 == other.position1 && position2 == other.position2) ||
               (position1 == other.position2 && position2 == other.position1);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // When implementing GetHashCode we have to follow the next rules:
        // 1. If two objects are equal then their hash codes must be equal too.
        // 2. Hash code must not change during the lifetime of the object.
        //    Therefore Move must be immutable. (Thanks to  Enigmativity's usefull tip).
        return position1 + position2;
    }
}
```

When you override `Object.Equals` you will be able to use condition `ListOfMoves.Contains(new Move(2, 3))` to check if moves `Move(2, 3)` or `Move(3, 2)` are contained in the `ListOfMoves`.

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pHHdwu) that demostrates overriding of `Object.Equals`.

Comment: The second rule with hash codes is that they cannot change over the lifetime of the object. `Move` must be immutable.

Comment: Your implementation will throw an exception if the passed object is not a `Move` instance. consider using casting with `as` operator.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you very much for your useful tip. I added it to the post. Also I made class `Move` immutable.

Comment: @orhtej2 Thank you for remark. I didn't want to complicate the sample therefore didn't include type checking and checking for reference equality. After your comment I decided to include these checks.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev my concern stemmed from the remark on linked document on `Object.Equals()` that the function is expected to always successfully return a value (and hence never throw).
Furthermore, an interesting point they're making is one should do exact type matching if the class is not `sealed` as comparison between base and derived class may yield unwanted results.

Comment: @orhtej2 Really interesting point about exact type matching if the class is not `sealed`. I have never thought about possibility of comparing base and derivded classes.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use LINQ's Any function. If you want both combinations for the positions [ (2,3) or (3,2) ] you'll need two pass in two checks

```
ListOfMoves.Any(x => 
    (x.position1 == 2 && x.position2 == 3) 
    || (x.position1 == 3 && x.position2 == 2) )
```

Any returns a bool so you can wrap this line of code in an if statement or store the result for multiple uses

**Potential improvement**

If you're going to be doing a lot of these checks (and you're using at least c# version 7) you could consider some minor refactoring and use the built in tuples type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Moves would become

```
public class Moves
{
    public (int position1, int position2) positions { get; set; }
}
```

And the Any call would become

```
ListOfMoves.Any(x => x.positions == (2,3) || x.positions == (3,2))
```

Else where in the code you can still access the underlying value of each position as so:

```
ListOfMoves[0].positions.position1
```

Obviously depends on what else is going on in your code so totally up to you!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it won't work cause you can't compare the entity itself rather you will have to compare with property values like below using `System.Linq`

```
ListOfMoves.Where(x => x.position1 == 2 && x.position1 == 3)
```

**Note:** Your posted code shouldn't compile at all in first place

You said .. *I need to get true if either Move(3,2) or (2,3) is in List*

Then use `Any()` using the same predicate like

```
if(ListOfMoves.Any(x => x.position1 == 2 && x.position1 == 3))
{
  // done something here
}
```

Comment: I know it does not compile. I wanted to show you that those positions are type int. I need to get true if either Move(3,2) or (2,3) is in List

Comment: But this code only checks position1? I am making dots&box game and I want to check if lines made a rectangle so I have to check 8 moves

Comment: You just have to do an or. `Any(x => (x.position1 == 2 && x.position2 == 3) || (position1 == 3 && x.position2 == 2))`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain it will be true if any of elements there, not both.

Comment: "Obviously it won't work cause you can't compare the entity itself" - no, this is not obvious - that's why the OP is asking.

Comment: Also, this code doesn't work. You need to check both properties.